# Strange font effect after when appending text to CEdit control

Tags: visual-c++, textbox, mfc, append, cedit

After noticing the slowness of the interface updating, I followed the advice on [CEdit SetWindowText rediculously slow](https://microsoft.public.vc.mfc.narkive.com/nRKzzCIG/cedit-setwindowtext-rediculously-slow) for appending text to a CEdit control.

Then I replaced

```
void CMyPropertyPage::Log(const CString& sLog)
{
    CString str;
    m_cLogEdit.GetWindowText(str);

    if (!str.IsEmpty())
        str += _T("\r\n");

    str += sLog;

    m_cLogEdit.SetWindowText(str);
    m_cLogEdit.LineScroll(m_cLogEdit.GetLineCount());
}
```

by

```
void CMyPropertyPage::Log(const CString& sLog)
{
    m_cLogEdit.SetSel(-1,-1);
    m_cLogEdit.ReplaceSel(sLog + L"\r\n");

    //m_cLogEdit.LineScroll(m_cLogEdit.GetLineCount());

    UpdateData(FALSE);
    UpdateWindow();
}
```

Now, when I run it, I notice a strange font blurring, as it is visible in the first two lines of the Log text box in the image.

What is the cause and how can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that code you have shown. It looks like cleartype font is not enabled on your system or your dialog, all the fonts look blurry. The edit control is not get repainted right for some reason. It looks like the first line was painted 4 times, the second line was painted 3 times ... and the last line was painted once, and background wasn't repainted. Show the dialog *.rc code and other info to reproduce this effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it :)

```
void CMyPropertyPage::Log(const CString& sLog)
{
    m_cLogEdit.SetRedraw(FALSE);

    m_cLogEdit.SetSel(-1,-1);
    m_cLogEdit.ReplaceSel(sLog + L"\r\n");

    m_cLogEdit.SetRedraw(TRUE);

    m_cLogEdit.LineScroll(m_cLogEdit.GetLineCount());

    UpdateData(FALSE);
    m_cLogEdit.UpdateWindow();
}
```

Seems if I disable the redraw temporarily the issue is gone!

Comment: And isn't it the way you said? I see them exactly in the way and order you described in my code!

Comment: Sorry, I have reading disability! That's the correct usage. Still you want to double check message overrides for `OnEraseBkgnd` etc. if any.

Comment: Would moving the .`SetRedraw(TRUE);` past the `LineScroll();` call make it crisper/cleaner?

Comment: @franji1 Yes, It makes sense to after, but things are working as they should right now!

Comment: Typically, the `SetRedraw FALSE/TRUE` calls need to be balanced/well-formed.  It may "work", but I would see if it works "correctly" by trying the `SetRedraw(TRUE)` after the `LineScroll` call.  If you DID try that and it did not work, I understand you not wanting to add the `SetRedraw(TRUE)` call..